# Import Json data in a JS variable simply

Tags: javascript, json

I made a js with data in a const array as below

```
   const messages = [
{ date: '2020-1-1', content:'message1'},
]
```

In order to make my file cleaner I decide to put the data in a Json file and want to call the Data in my Js in order to use it like before.

my Json is like this

```
[
   {
      "date":"2020-1-1",
      "content":"message1"
    }
]
```

In order to import my Json I put this code:

```
let messages = [];
$.getJSON("messages.json", function(data) {
messages = data;
console.log(messages);
});
```

The result is that my array is loaded in the console but the variable dont work, I tried things with Object.keys but no more result. I dont use framework also and dont find a solution on other questions here. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: It works just fine, how do you access messages after it is being filled? Share me the script code after your $.getJSON().

Comment: Alvin, I put my answer to your comment in another answer in order to be readable.

Comment: You should just use `JSON.stringify`. You don't need jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont use framework

You are using a library, though, `$ === jQuery`

> in order to make my file cleaner I decide to put the data in a Json file

You can just define a `constants.js` file and load that before your other scripts.

For example,

`constants.js`

```
const messages = [
  { date: '2020-1-1', content:'message1'},
]
```

`main.js`

```
alert(messages);
```

`index.html`

```
<script src="constants.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is probably the issue. `$.getJSON()` is an async function, the code will not wait until the closing curly bracket of the method:

```
var start = x;
$.getJSON('messages.json', function(data) {
   messages = data;
}); <-- this
var end = z;
```

The code will run `var end = z;` before the `$.getJSON()` finished getting the result, because it is asynchronous function. In other word, when the code is currently at `var end = z`, `$.getJSON()` is still working to get the data, and has not been finished. That is why the `messages = data` is not being called yet.

So here is what you want to do:

```
$.getJSON('messages.json', function(data) {
    messages = data;

    for (const item of messages) {
        if (item.date === todayDay) {
            console.log(item.content);

            var newPara = document.createElement("p");
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(item.content);
            newPara.appendChild(textNode);
            var nodeParent = document.getElementById("titre");
            var nodeChild = document.getElementById("child1");
            nodeParent.appendChild(newPara, nodeChild);

        }
    }
});
```

Do all your needed operations within the curly bracket of

```
$.getJSON('messages.json', function(data) {
    //The data is finished being filled here
}
```

This is a callback function. You can learn more about callback function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp)

---

### Some Info

Yes the loop has to be inside the callback function to run after the data has been retrieved. To give you better understanding about the async function, you can also put your loop outside within a timeout function, but you will never want this, because you will not know how long the operation for retrieving the data will run.

For example:

```
$.getJSON('messages.json', function(data) {
   messages = data;
});

setTimeout(function() { 
    for (const item of messages) {
        if (item.date === todayDay) {
            console.log(item.content);

            var newPara = document.createElement("p");
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(item.content);
            newPara.appendChild(textNode);
            var nodeParent = document.getElementById("titre");
            var nodeChild = document.getElementById("child1");
            nodeParent.appendChild(newPara, nodeChild);

        }
    }
}, 2000); //run after 2 seconds
```

Im sure the code above will also work, the process of getting the data should not be longer than 2 seconds.

Again this is not a correct way to do it, just to give you better understanding of async function.

Answer (score 0):

@Alvin Stefanus
Because x,z and messages were undefined and didnt let the code work, I also add

```
let messages,x,z = [];
```

And now it works perfectly with your solution.
I will use it as you told also for the other operations.
Thank you very much it helped for my problem and gave me a new technique.

EDIT:
I also tried to delete this part

```
var start = x;
$.getJSON('messages.json', function(data) {
   messages = data;
}); <-- this
var end = z;
```

And it also works! That means that the problem was not the async function but because I didnt put the loop within the curly bracket of

```
$.getJSON('messages.json', function(data) {
    //The data is finished being filled here
}
```